# How to print all lines that user typed

Tags: java

the program first take a number that user typed which is the number of lines that user want to type..

but I want to print every line that user typed but it doesn't work 
it just prints the last line!

here is the code

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int x=in.nextInt();
    String s="";

    if (x >=1 && x<= 10000)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<=x;i++)
        {
             s=in.nextLine();

        }

    }

    System.out.println(s);
```

Example

here is the input

2

hello

world

the output

world

Comment: You're off-by one with your loop condition `i < x` and you replace `s` with every iteration of your loop; I think you were supposed to use an array to store each line (but you could possibly use a `StringBuilder`). Please read an [open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166/108326), and take the site [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not storing the previous strings anywhere. You're just disposing them.

In order to store them, you can use an array. Like this:

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int x=in.nextInt();
    String s = new String[x];

    if (x >=1 && x<= 10000)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<=x;i++)
        {
             s[i]=in.nextLine();

        }

    }

        for(int i=0;i<=x;i++)
        {
             System.out.println(s[i]);
        }
```

Comment: thank you ..  it says that arrayInedxOutOfBoundExceptio so i made it like this String[x+1] and it works

Comment: I'm glad it did. Consider accepting my answer so others know it has been solved

Answer (score 0):

It's due to override of your String S Every time the inner for loop i.e for(int i=0;i<=x;++i) runs the inner value of the string s is override so that's the reasons why it always print the last word only when the loop is Exits.
Why not to try this as:

```html
import java.util.Scanner;
public class abc {
    public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many line you want to input=\t");
    int x=in.nextInt();
    String s="";
        if (x >=1 && x<= 10000)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<=x;i++)
        {
            s=in.nextLine();
            System.out.print(s);

        }

    }
```